# ¿Problema con edición de imágenes en drupal 7?

Tags: imagen, drupal, drupal7

Tengo un cliente que me pide editar su web Drupal. Núnca antes usé Drupal. Es Drupal 7. He buscado, rebuscado y remirado donde editar las imágenes. Por ejemplo en la home tengo un anuncio de un congreso y quiero cambiar esa imagen, pero cuándo la busco no la encuentro.
Adjunto imagen de mis secciones de admin:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es muy raro, porque solo consigo acceder a ver donde están las imágenes cuando le digo en un artículo que quiero añadir una imagen, entonces allí aparece un botón que se llama `ver servidor` entonces si que me aparecen todas las carpetas con todas las imágenes.

Comment: aquí puedes aprender Drupal : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/drupal/index.htm saludos :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por defecto en Drupal 7 no hay una manera de ver todas las imágenes desde el panel de administración, tienes que entrar por FTP y si no se ha cambiado nada la imágenes deberían estar en `sites/default/files`.

Por lo que dices de *"ver servidor"* supongo que se está usando el módulo IMCE para subir las imágenes, en ese caso si vas a **Configuración** y en el bloque **MEDIA** pinchas en IMCE te aparecen un par de tablas, si pinchas en la cabecera  `PUBLIC FILES` te abre el navegador de archivos.

Answer (score 1):

Los sitios en Drupal y el contenido dentro del sitio se llaman nodos, para entrar y cambiar una imagen puede haberlo hecho de varias formas:

1. Creando un campo de imagen en un nodo, por lo tanto, tienes que buscar en contenido y luego el nodo que deseas cambiar en la imagen, si no sabes cuál es, la mejor forma de buscar el nodo es la siguiente.

Le das en inspeccionar elemento, luego en la etiqueta `body`, por ahi dice `node`, y si dice eso busca el `node-id` que vendria siendo el `node-123` o algo asi. Ese es el nº de id del nodo, por lo tanto, para entrar a ese nodo tienes que escribir en la url `sites.com/node/123/edit`, y asi editas el nodo, y buscas la imagen que deseas cambiar.